# Laravel 5.2 - is it safe to add public $incrementing = false; for every eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel-5

For Laravel 5.2, is it safe to add `public $incrementing = false;` for every eloquent model, even if the model does use an auto incrementing id as a primary key? By setting `$incrementing` to false, at least it saves me the trouble when I am using a string etc. as a primary key.

What's the gain to set $incrementing to true? I don't quite get it.

Comment: The gain is to have auto-incrementing id's, which is a fairly common thing to want. And I don't see why it would not be safe to add, can you explain your concerns?

Comment: I upgraded my project from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2, and some functionality failed because there was no `public $incrementing = false;` added before. So I am considering to add this line to all models.